# Why StreamWriter dosent work good inside a paint event? Getting big red x in the pictureBox

Tags: c#

I have a pictureBox1 paint event.
In the paint event im writing to a text file some information:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                SolidBrush brush;
                Pen p=null;
               Point connectionPointStart;
               Point connectionPointEnd;
               Graphics g = e.Graphics;
               g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                   brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                   p = new Pen(brush);
                   for (int idx = 0; idx < wireObject1._point_X.Count; ++idx)
                   {
                       Point dPoint = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[idx], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[idx]);
                       dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
                       dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
                       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
                       g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                       // g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
                   }

                   for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
                   {

                       int startIndex = wireObject1._connectionstart[i];
                       int endIndex = wireObject1._connectionend[i];



                       connectionPointStart = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[startIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[startIndex]);
                       connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[endIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[endIndex]);
                       p.Width = 4;
                       g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
                       moveCounter++;
                       textBox1.Text = moveCounter.ToString();
                       if (moveCounter > 10)
                       {
                           w.WriteLine("Number Of Moves ===>   " + moveCounter);
                       }
                   }

            }

In the bottom i have a w.WriteLine....
In the top of Form1 i did StreamWriter w;
In the constructor i did: w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt");

In the pictureBox1 mouse up event im doing w.Close();

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {

                if (mouseMove == true)
                {
                    Point NewPoint = e.Location;
                    wireObject1._point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
                    wireObject1._point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
                    mouseMove = false;
                    if (moveCounter == 0)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        w.Close();
                    }
                    WireObjectCoordinatesCloneFrame();

                }

            }
```

So i move the mouse its recording writing to the file the information from the variable moveCounter wich is type of int.

The problem is when i make the mouse up event and its closing the file in the pictureBox1 i see a BIG RED X with white background.
The file it self is ok on the hard disk with all the information as i wanted.

But why the big red x is appear in the pictureBox1 ? If i remove the w.WriteLine from the paint event so i dont see the big red x.

What can i do to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've closed the stream writer, you're still trying to write to it in the paint event. That will fail (you can't write to a closed stream), so the paint event handler will throw an exception - causing the red X to appear.

It's pretty bizarre to perform any IO during a paint event, to be honest... what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Jon Skeet i want to write to a text file the number of times its drawing al ine in the paint event. My program i did that i add two points click a button connect them with a line. Then i can move the connected points drag them around the pictureBox area so when i drag the points when they are connected its entering to the loop in the paint event. So i want to write the moveCounter to the text file to see how many times it was entering this area in the paint event.

Comment: I tried to move this if (moveCounter > 10)
                    {
                        w.WriteLine("Number Of Moves ===>   " + moveCounter);
                    } from the paint event to the move event so now im not getting red x in the pictureBox but in the text file i see the numbers twice or more for each number for example. i see 11 and 11 and 11 then 12 12 12 12 then 13 13 then 14 14 then 15 15 15 and so on...i dont know why its writing it sometimes double in a row ?

Comment: @user1477444: Writing to a file in a UI handler (especially paint, which can get called a *lot*) is a really bad idea. It would be better to keep the counter in memory and possibly write it *periodically*. I'm not sure why you're seeing duplicate values though - a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be helpful there. I'd suggest putting that in a new question though; I think this one is now answered.